# Lookup Operation Slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
query = [{
    $match: {
      $and: [{
        feed: {
          $in: feeds
        }
      }, {
        updatedAt: {
          $gte: new Date(date)
        }
      }
    ]
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "feed",
      localField: "feed",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "feed"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$feed",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "source",
      localField: "feed.source",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "feed.source",
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      updatedAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: limit
  },
  {
    $skip: skip
  }
];
```

The query is taking too long, about 10 seconds to be specific.

I read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/ but it is still rather slow.

I am looking to optimize as much as possible, is there a way? The collection is indexed for $updatedAt: -1

Any ideas?

Comment: Asking *"this is slow, how to make faster?"* is generally a broad and subjective question. Nearly all actions are generally resolved by putting an index in place that resolves the number of matches most efficiently. Your input basically has two fields as criteria, and generally speaking the *"finite list"* on `$in` is **usually** the one that would match the least items when given an index to match against. Hence, the condition that reduces the matches the most "should" be the one that you primarily want to index on.

Comment: Beyond that, questions like this are entirely subjective. Bottom line here is that you are in fact *"Performing Joins"* using a product that allows for structured data in such ways as to generally avoid the issues with "performing joins" in the first place. So if there really is not some practical reason why you should not **embed the data** in the first place, then embedding is generally the better option. Hence the change in your question title, since we may as well call it for what it is.

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I have my reasons for not embedding the data, thus my question. Semantics aside, it seems the correct answer is, "No, there is no way to improve your query due to your data model".

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to run fast I'd advise removing the `$lookup` pipeline stages and modeling your document based on its usage.

You could however add an index on the first match part of the aggregation query (updatedAt, feed). But you'll still have the problem that you are still looking up from 2 other collections which wont use any indexes.

> The $match and $sort pipeline operators can take advantage of an index when they occur at the beginning of the pipeline.

https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes

Comment: Any `$lookup` stages can also take advantage of a suitable index. As at MongoDB 3.4, the `$lookup` will be an equality query on the `<from>` collection for each source document. I've raised [DOCS-10681](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10681) to update the documentation with more information.

Comment: Ah I never knew this, thanks for information I'll update my answer